# Unable to access tables created with sqlite3 from a program using the C API

Tags: c++, sqlite

I generate an sqlite3 database file (call it db.sl3; invoked interactively as `$ sqlite3 db.sl3` from a shell) from within the sqlite3 commandline program, for instance

```
create table people (
        id              integer,
        firstname       varchar(20),
        lastname        varchar(20),
        phonenumber     char(10)
);   
insert into people (id, firstname, lastname, phonenumber) values
        (1, 'Fred', 'Flintstone', '5055551234');    
insert into people (id, firstname, lastname, phonenumber) values
        (2, 'Wilma', 'Flintstone', '5055551234');    
insert into people (id, firstname, lastname, phonenumber) values
        (3, 'Barny', 'Rubble', '5055554321');
```

I am trying to use this in a program I have written which uses the sqlite3 C API; however, whenever I attempt to open up the database file in the C program using either

```
sqlite3* db;
rc = sqlite3_open( "db.sl3", &db );
```

or

```
rc = sqlite3_open_v2( "db.sl3", &db, SQLITE_READONLY, 0 );
```

followed by a query where the SQL is contained in the following string

```
std::string sqlCmd = "select * from sqlite_master where type='table' order by name";
```

to the `sqlite3_get_table wrapper` interface invoked as follows

```
rc = sqlite3_get_table( db, sqlCmd.c_str(), &result, &numRows, &numCols, &errorMsg );
```

The return code (`rc`) is 0 in either case implying that there was no problem with the operation but there are no tables entries recorded in the `result` variable.  I have tried all sorts of pathing issues (e.g., using absolute paths to the db file, relative, only in the invocation directory, etc.) to no avail.  Also, when I reopen the database file with the sqlite3 commandline program I can see the tables and their entries.  As an aside, if I open, create and insert the lines into the table in the C program I can access them fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Am I not properly initializing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default **sqlite3_open** will create the database if it does not exist (equivalent with calling **sqlite3_open_v2** with flags=S*QLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE*) - and rc will be *SQLITE_OK*.

I've tried [this](http://pastebin.com/00374Y9m) test program against a database created using sqlite3 and each time (existing db with people table: full path, relative; existing 0 sized db: full path, relative; nonexistent db: full path, relative) **sqlite3_open_v2** behaved as advertised.

Try to do a 'sqlite3 [full_path_to_db]' then run the query and compare the results with what your program or mine does (again with [full_path_to_db]) just in case your **sqlite3_open** tests created some 0 sized db.sl3 which are then gadly opened by **sqlite3_open_v2** .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Only after a long time of troubleshooting did I post this question.  What I did after posting waiting for a response was to try a much simpler program like the one you linked with the database.  Worked fine.  The problem ended up being an unrelated filename issue in a different part of the program (which was probably the most likely problem to begin with).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to know you've figured it out.